# php: how fgets works?

Tags: php, html

I wanted to make html pages for writing easier, so I made a small PHP script.
It should be read from a text file and write them in html format.

html page says: `";} fclose ($ f);?>`, although it should say:
Hi!
This is test.

My code:

```
<div class="b_3">
<h2>Artikkelin nimi</h2>
<?php
    $f = fopen("Tekstilaatikko.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($f)) { 
        echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
    }
    fclose($f);
?>
</div>
```

I am sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your code works good. Does your folder running `.php` file has the text file as `Tekstilaatikko.txt` ?

Comment: Oh, I run it in .html mode :D
Now it works!
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the file `Tekstilaatikko.txt` in the folder that your `.php` file is located.

Note :

Also file should have the extension `.php`

(If you want to have your file as .html extension, you need to do some additional configuration)